# Pomodoro application which shows time in menubar

Tags: software-recommendation, productivity

Please advice a **free** application for [Pomodoro time management](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) which:

- Can be minified to menubar and shows remaining time there (like [tomighty](http://www.tomighty.org/)):

[image: tomighty]

- Has a tasklist (like [pomodairo](https://code.google.com/p/pomodairo/)):

[image: Pomodairo]

---

Here is what I dislike about  mentioned apps:

*Pomodairo* can't be minified in menubar (instead it has annoying mini window which covers application you work in)

[image: Pomodairo miniwindow]

*Tomighty* is a timer without tasklist so you need to keep tasks on paper which I don't really like.

---

Here is [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/224265/pomodoro-timer-for-linux) I've asked at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/224265/pomodoro-timer-for-linux).

Comment: there is also wunderlist which is made with appcelerator Titanium. It GLITCHED a lot and it's not pomodoro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pomodoro](http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/) looks like it might do what you need.

- Can be minified to menubar and shows remaining time there (✔)
- Has a tasklist (possible ✔) Its called a log in the app and the webpage says for each timer you can "add a meaningful description, press Ok and pomodoro starts")

[image]

The latest release is [available on the MAS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pomodoro/id417574133?mt=12&ls=1) for $5. However, the developers site also says you can either download an older version for free, or build the latest source yourself:

> Buy the latest approved release from the Mac App Store℠, go to the
>   [Downloads](http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/pages/downloads.html) section to get old 0.31 binaries, or access the [source](http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/pages/source.html) at
>   the git repository to compile on your own the latest and greatest
>   version.
>
> Pomodoro is open source: you can donate a small amount of money if you
>   really liked it and don't want to buy it from Mac App Store℠.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's downloadable from the website anymore; everything seems to redirect to the blog.

Answer (score 0):

[Activity Timer](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/activity-timer/id808647808?mt=12) works well. It's free (as in free beer) in the App Store and it integrates well in the task bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/ivoronin/TomatoBar
It's free and open source.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/320760)